# C# - Calling overridden methods in derived classes in order of inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract

I would like to be able to call overridden methods in the order in which the are derived.

For example in the following code I create a new class named **CallMeThird** and when calling its `CallMe` method I would like it execute the base classes `CallMe` methods in order of inheritance:

- CallMeFirst
- CallMeSecond
- CallMeThird

There are a couple of things I would like to avoid though:

- Calling `base.CallMe` in the derived classes
- The use of `OnCallMeFirst` and `OnCallMeSecond` as `CallMe` is still exposed to the derived classes and the code will likely become confusing.

Is there a nice, clean pattern that I can use for this case?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Base b = new CallMeThird();
            b.CallMe();

            while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {

            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class Base
    {
        public abstract void CallMe();
    }

    public class CallMeFirst : Base
    {
        public override void CallMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I would like to be called first");
        }
    }

    public class CallMeSecond : CallMeFirst
    {
        public override void CallMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I would like to be called second");
        }
    }

    public class CallMeThird : CallMeSecond
    {
        public override void CallMe()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I would like to be called third");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Chain of responsibility, maybe. Can't really say given this little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `base.CallMe();` to each override, that way it will chain up your inheritance hierarchy.

You can want to avoid it all you like, but it is the solution. Overriding means replacement, if you want to use the parent classes implementation, you best call it.

However, I don't see the need for inheritance here. If the CallMeThird just uses CallMeSecond (and so on) rather than needing to be interchangeable with it, [I would prefer composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). Which would mean CallMeThird would contain CallMeSecond and return a call to it's CallMe method. The example is to stripped down to know if your problem is a composition or inheritance problem, however.

Comment: I thought this might be the only real sensible solution.  Will do this unless a  new pattern emerges.

Answer (score 1):

As Nathan points out, the ability to call through `base` exists to do specifically this and it is likely the easiest, cleanest, most performant and most stable way to achieve what you want. Thus, I would recommend against [avoiding the feature that exists specifically to solve your problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/06/10391383.aspx), unless you have a requirement that demands this.

However, if you're absolutely sure you want to avoid that for any reason, here's a possible alternative:

1. Avoid polymorphism (make these methods non-virtual).
2. Define a custom attribute.
3. Decorate the desired method in every class with that attribute.
4. In the method you have in your base class, use reflection to build the chain of inheritance (from the base class up until the actual class of the object).
5. For every type in the chain, select the method that's decorated with your attribute.
6. For the resulting method sequence, invoke each method in the order you want.

Comment: So to summarise: Here is a section of rope you can hang yourself with ;D

Comment: @NathanCooper I wouldn't say you hang yourself when you do this. Lots of frameworks do similar things and, if done correctly, it works fine. However, it's not as fast, or as easy as the `base` call and you have to define what happens when the hierarchy isn't as you expect it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [Template Method](http://www.dofactory.com/net/template-method-design-pattern) to avoid using multiple inheritance.